# Simple_form override input, and textarea class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Is it possible to change the default "string" class on both input, and textarea to be my own default class that I can choose?

And by this i mean in my simple_form.rb initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Refer [custom inputs section](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs) of the simple forms gem's README.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest build for the gem you can change it in your in your initializer by typing in `config.input_class = 'your-class'` but this will then affect all form input field classes.